# When is a group homomorphism surjective?

Tags: group-theory

This may be a silly question, but for some group homomorphism $\phi $, how do we know if it is surjective? E.g a question I have is show there are no such $\phi : \mathit S_9 \rightarrow \mathbb Z_7 \times \mathbb Z_3$ with image $=$ $\mathbb Z_7 \times \mathbb Z_3$. This is one of a few such homomorphisms mentioned in questions I have, and in the soutions they are always surjective but no explanation is given why. Any tips?

Comment: What do you know about normal subgroups of $S_9$. How many are there?

Comment: @DerekHolt Honestly? I have no idea, other than $Alt_9$

Comment: So $\ker(\phi)$ is what?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I guess I misread the question: If we assume the image is  $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ then by definition $R/ker(\phi)$ is isomorphic to it, and as a result of the isomorphism theorem $\phi$ is surjective? What's also confusing me more for this question is, for some $x$ in $S_9$, if we let $|(x)\phi| = 21$ then $|x|$ divides  $21$, but to show they are equal I need $\phi$ to be injective. The solutions jump straight to showing $S_9$ has no element of order 21, but why does this need to be the case? There is nothing to say $\phi$ is injective.

Comment: The question is, why there is no surjective homomorphism $\phi\colon S_9\rightarrow \Bbb Z_3\times \Bbb Z_7$. The answer follows just from the isomorphism lemma with kernel and image, because we know the kernels here, and also the image.

Comment: @DietrichBurde So I found a lemma that says for $n\geq5$ then only $A_n$ is normal for $S_n$. Since the kernel is normal, $S_9 / A_9 \cong \mathbb Z_7 \times \mathbb Z_3$, but even knowing this I don't see the solution. Why do we require that $S_9$ has an element of order 21?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Hold on, it is simply because $S_9/A_9$ is of the form $[{A_9 s :s\in S_9}]$, which due to the isomorphism theorem requires an element of order 21 (which it doesn't have)?

Comment: "Even worse". It is simply because $S_9/A_9$ has only $2$ elements, and $\Bbb Z_3 \times \Bbb Z_7$ has $21$ elements. How can there be an isomorphism then? We have $2\neq 21$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi: S_9 \to \mathbb{Z_7}\times\mathbb{Z_3}$ surjective homomorphism.
We know that -
$$\forall x\in S_9 : o(\phi(x)) | o(x)$$
$\mathbb{Z_7}\times\mathbb{Z_3}$ is cyclic group (why?), then  $\exists y\in \mathbb{Z_7}\times\mathbb{Z_3}$ such that $o(y)=21$
since $\phi$ is surjective , we have some $k\in S_9$ such that $\phi(k)=y$
so $o(\phi(k)) | o(k) \rightarrow o(y) | o(k) \rightarrow 21 | o(k)$

What is the maximal order of element in $S_9$ ?
once you found out , you will be able to solve the question.
Good luck!

Comment: This is a more satisfactory proof than the one involving quotients of $S_9$, because  it is mroe elementary and requires no knowledge of the normal subgroups of $S_9$.